# How would I make a meta redirect that redirects to the URL stored in the parameter?

Tags: html, url, redirect, parameters

I am attempting to setup a service which will redirect the user to a URL stored in the `?url=` parameter, how would I do this?

I have tried using meta

```
http-equiv="refresh"
```

with

```
out.print(request.getParameter("ur;")) %>
```

however all that happens is the page reloads in a loop. Not too sure if I need to use quotation marks (e.g /?url="https://google.com")

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
      content="0; URL="<%
out.print(request.getParameter("redirect")) %>">
```

What I need to happen is when the user gets redirected to "https://example.com/exampledir/index.html?url=https://anotherwebsite.com" (just an example url) the script on index.html will get the parameter and redirect to it exactly. What actually happens is the page just reloads in a loop.

Comment: `<% out.print(request.getParameter("ur;")) %>` What language is this supposed to be? This is not how JavaScript works.

Comment: My bad, not that good with javascript, so I ended up making with what I had.

Comment: If you'd like a solution using JavaScript, please leave the JavaScript tag on the question. I was trying to clarify if you were using some kind of server-side technology—`<% … %>` looks like ASP or possibly JSP, though I'm really not familiar with it—or some template language—`<% … %>` could also be EJS. If you *are* using some other language or tools for generating HTML, it's important to note that in the question as well.

Comment: I haven't setup any server-side stuff and rather just using it to host the file where the browser does most of the work and redirects straight to the URL in the parameter. However, cannot seem to be able to even read the parameter. I have done some research and it did seem like JSP which is what I had been doing incorrect all this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using any server-side language, you won't be able to generate a different meta tag during rendering. Instead, you'll need to do this with JavaScript after the page loads.

Add a script tag to the bottom of the page like this:

```
<script>
  var redirect = new URL(window.location).searchParams.get('redirect');
  if (redirect) window.location = redirect;
</script>
```

Now if you browse to the page like this: `http://<myserver>/myfile.html?redirect=https://google.com` you'll be redirected to `https://google.com`.

For reference, see MDN articles on:

- [`Window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)
- [`URL.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

I also highly recommend you read through [Java​Script basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics) just to make sure you understand the overall concepts presented here.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, and yes, I am pretty new to JavaScript, so therefore I will be sure to take a look at it.